# Working with haven_labelled_spss - data looses "label" after setting NA values

Tags: r

I have a `labelled_spss` dataset, imported with 
`haven::read_sav("path/file.sav", user_na = TRUE)`. Somehow, after using `labelled::na_values` I loose the `label`-tag in my attributes and I can't figure out why.

An example:

```
#Before
attributes(a$q24)
```

> $label
>   [1] "If tomorrow would be a referendum, how would you vote?"
>
> $format.spss
>    [1] "F3.0"
>
> $class
>    [1] "haven_labelled"
>
> $labels
>    Country should be in Union  Country should leave            wouldn't vote 
>                                    1                                  2                                966 
>            don't know 
>                                  977

```r
# Setting NA
na_values(a$q24) <- 977
attributes(a$q24)
```

> $format.spss
>    [1] "F3.0"
>
> $class
>    [1] "haven_labelled"
>
> $labels
>    Country should be in Union  Country should leave            wouldn't vote 
>                                    1                                  2                                966 
>            don't know 
>                                  977
>
> $na_values
>   [1] 977

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in `labelled`. It should be fixed in the development version.